# Maven - Publishing Multiple Sub-Modules/Artifacts

Tags: maven, gradle

I have a Kotlin project organised like so:

```
project-name
    > project-name-core
    > project-name-domain
```

My gradle publishing script is set up like this:

```
publishing {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    publications.all {
        pom.withXml(configureMavenCentralMetadata)
    }
    publications {
        mavenPublication(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            groupId 'com.project'
            artifactId 'project-name'
            artifact sourcesJar
            artifact javadocJar
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal` I can see `project-name` in the local repository cache, but not `project-name-core` or `project-name-domain`.

How do I configure gradle to publish my sub-modules to the maven local repository cache?

Comment: @VishwaRatna that's already applied - not working

Comment: Have you tried adding `mavenLocal()` to each project individually?

Comment: @VishwaRatna Yes. Still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess is that you only applied the publishing plugin to the **root** project and not the subprojects.

If you intend to publish the root project (`src/`) in addition to the subprojects, then you should move the configurations to the `allprojects` block:

```
allprojects {
    publishing {
        publications.all {
            pom.withXml(configureMavenCentralMetadata)
        }
        publications {
            mavenPublication(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
                groupId 'com.project'
                artifactId 'project-name'
                artifact sourcesJar
                artifact javadocJar
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise if you only want to publish the subprojects, then replace `allprojects` with `subprojects`

Also, you don't need to add configure the repositories with `mavenLocal()`.