# How to publish a multi-module Gradle project to local Maven repository?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have a Gradle library project which has multiple modules, somewhat like this:

```
ModuleA (aka. the main module)
 ^- ModuleB
 ^- ModuleC
     ^- ModuleD
```

Each of these modules has external dependencies as well. Inside this project, all works fine and dandy. Now, I want to publish this project as a dependency so that I can easily integrate everything to another project (all modules A-D, as well as the external dependencies). However, when I publish to local Maven repository with `publishToMavenLocal`, only the classes from ModuleA are available in the consumer project.

How do I configure the project so that the consumer project gets to use everything from the library project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the publishing plugin to allprojects instead of **root** project.

Try [Maven - Publishing Multiple Sub-Modules/Artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59732223/maven-publishing-multiple-sub-modules-artifacts).